# Why is WebKit written in C++ and not in ObjectiveC

Tags: c++, objective-c

Apple is the backing force of ObjectiveC.

However WebKit is written in C++.

Apart from portability (not all systems have ObjectiveC compilers/runtimes) is there any other valid reason for this? Performance, features?

Lately Apple does not seem to care of other languages than ObjectiveC.

Comment: As Jeremy points, WebKit is a fork of KHTML, written mostly in C++. Remember, not every program under Jobs' sun has to be written in Obj-C

Comment: "Apple" isn't a monolithic entity (the supreme court's views on corporate personhood be damned), and as such doesn't "care" about any language, include Objective-C.  Groups at Apple, like any successful company, use what they judge to be the best tool for the job, for reasons that can range from performance to "we based X off of some other project, and it used that language" to an engineer's whim.

Comment: Sorry, I do not agree with the reason for closing this question.  It is possible to answer it objectively (excuse the pun).  It's written in C++ because it is a fork of KHTML.  End of story.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Aside from portability, the use of C++ is an historical artefact. [WebKit wasn't started by Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#History); it was a fork of KHTML, which was developed as part of the KDE project. The decision to use C++ was made by the KHTML team, likely because KDE itself is [written in C++ using the Qt framework](http://www.kde.org/community/getinvolved/development/).

Comment: "the use of C++ is an historical artefact" <-- lies and misspellings

Comment: Don't you think "lies" is a word both too strong and inadequate on SO?

Comment: "Artefact" is a common spelling, with about [320k hits](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=artefact) in the literature indexed by Google Scholar. As for "lies," please be so kind as to provide some sort of citation. "Lies" is inaccurate, as I am not stating something I know to be factually incorrect - in fact, I believe it to be factually correct, as KDE is a itself [written in C++ using Qt](http://www.kde.org/community/getinvolved/development/).

Comment: @JimDaniel: "Artefact" is no more incorrect than "colour" or "theatre." British English ≠ illiteracy

Comment: I think JimDaniel may be using the misspelling tag to refer to the use of the indefinite article 'an' as opposed to 'a' before 'historical'. Just to clarify, this is correct.

Comment: "artefact" is actually preferred in British English. See: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-art1.htm

Comment: Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage allows "both a and an are used in writing a historic an historic. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles and http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a[2]

Comment: @Chuck, @Joseph: Well played.

Comment: This discussion of British spellings is quite tyre-ing.  *ducks*

Comment: Okay okay, jeez. :) People still use C++ for new development, though.

Comment: The original post resides in Atlanta.  Isn't it common practice in programming to conform to the local style, even if you really don't like to add braces for single-statement `if` blocks? :)

Comment: I don't even think Jeremy was trying to say that the use of C++ is generally to be considered a thing of the past. Only that maybe, had Apple been the ones who started WebKit, they wouldn't have done it in C++.

Comment: @Joseph: Bingo. That WebKit uses C++ is a product of WebKit's history as a fork of KHTML, which was begun by KDE developers accustomed to using C++.

Comment: I quite liked this completely useless discussion. But that's just me :D

Comment: @Jim: he didn't say C++ is never used for new development. Just that its use in WebKit is for historical reasons.

Comment: Well, I'm going to hide under a rock.

Answer (score 3):

WebKit was originally forked from KHTML, which is written in C++. This, and the fact that it is "more" portable (not really, but it's hard to find ObjC developers for other platforms) probably contributed to Apple not rewriting it in ObjC. This has proven to be a good decision lately, after Google picked it up for their own browser, Chrome, which has resulted in several major contributions and thus a very up-to-date/on-the-edge renderer.

Answer (score 1):

WebKit is a fork of KHTML which was written in C++...

You will ask me... Why KHTML was written in C++ ? I do not know.

Comment: KHTML was part of KDE, a (german based) project to port the mhh... let's say "Windows Desktop Experience" to Linux. The KDE project is C++ based.

Comment: Ok, thanks ZJR. I like your "Windows Desktop Experience" quotes.

Comment: I won't ask... Although KDE's C++ was weird (MOC)at least for KDE 1,2

Answer (score 1):

Check the [WebKit](http://webkit.org) homepage.  It is a branch of the KHTML library used in Konqueror, so Apple really had nothing to do with deciding what language it was written in.

Comment: KHTML, not Konqueror. There's a difference between *browser* and *rendering engine*.

Comment: Edited before you pointed it out, but thanks.  Having one of those days.